# .NET 3.5 - is there any other way to Zip files

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, zip

I am aware of System.IO.Packaging and System.IO.Compression for compressing the files in .NET 3.5. To Zip files System.IO.Packaging is quiet handy.
I am aware of the free libraries that can be used to Zip it.

My Question - Is there any other way other than that to Zip file in .NET 3.5?

Comment: If you have the inbuilt ones (`System.IO.Packaging.ZipPackage` in particular) and the OSS ones... how many do you need? what sort of answer are you looking for, here?

Comment: I am looking for something other than System.IO.Packaging, when zip file is created it is having an extra xml file which is raising lot of questions. I am trying to avoid it but at the same time I can use only inbuilt features and not those which are available outside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ZipPackage` exists from 3.0, but yes - it seems to include an annoying `[Content_Types].xml` and has no option to remove it. A new `ZipArchive` was added in 4.5, but obviously you aren't there yet. The only other option that leaps to mind is to use [interop to shell32](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34165/How-to-Utilise-the-Shell32-Library-in-NET-as-a-COM) - not very pretty, but it might just work.

Comment: SO, here are the findings so far - 1. Using System.IO.Packaging we can use ZipPackage to create Zip. 2. Using FileStream create empty Zip and then use Shell32.dll's CopyHere method to add files in Zip. BOTH WORKED FILE... Lets wait to find out if anyone can come up any other option...